# Reproduce the example code showed in as-if rule of cppreference

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to reproduce the example code in order to understand the *as-if rule* of C++ better. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

```
int& preinc(int& n) { return ++n; }
int add(int n, int m) { return n+m; }

// volatile input to prevent constant folding
volatile int input = 7;

// volatile output to make the result a visible side-effect
volatile int result;

int main()
{
    int n = input;
// using built-in operators would invoke undefined behavior
//    int m = ++n + ++n;
// but using functions makes sure the code executes as-if 
// the functions were not overlapped
    int m = add(preinc(n), preinc(n));
    result = m;
}
```

I use `g++ -s main.cpp` to get the assembler output from the source, the  `main()` function of output file `main.s` is showed as below:

```
main:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_offset 3, -24
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    input(%rip), %eax
    movl    %eax, -32(%rbp)
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _Z6preincRi
    movl    (%rax), %ebx
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _Z6preincRi
    movl    (%rax), %eax
    movl    %ebx, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    _Z3addii
    movl    %eax, -28(%rbp)
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, result(%rip)
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rdx
    je  .L7
    call    __stack_chk_fail
```

According to the output file I think the g++ compiler only compile the source code sentence by sentence without optimization, even if I add the `-O3` compile option.

Since the output suppose to be like this:

```
# full code of the main() function as produced by the GCC compiler
# x86 (Intel) platform:
        movl    input(%rip), %eax   # eax = input
        leal    3(%rax,%rax), %eax  # eax = 3 + eax + eax
        movl    %eax, result(%rip)  # result = eax
        xorl    %eax, %eax          # eax = 0 (the return value of main())
        ret
```

I want to know how to get the assembler output code showed as below.

Comment: It would be nice to see the C++ code that generated that assembly code.

Comment: Can't reproduce what you say: https://godbolt.org/z/OqPFyD

Comment: That is the expected output without optimisation.

Comment: With -O2 or -O3 it works as expected

Comment: Thanks, I found I was wrong. It works correct with -O2 or -O3. Thanks the website Julian gave. I will modified my question later.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong when I test the example code. Here is the answer I made concluding some of my thoughts and the comments from others above.

Compilers will optimize the code unless the "-O3" or "-O2" compilation option was added. Just like @Balázs Kovacsics and @molbdnilo said in comments. Using the command `g++ -S main.cpp` will get the assembler output sentence by sentence like what is showed in the question.

Once the "-O3" or "-O2" compilation option was added, it means programmer allows the compiler do any code transformations that do not change the observable behavior of the program. So the `main()` function of output file `main.s` is showed as below, using `g++ -S -O3 main.cpp`

```
main:
.LFB2:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    input(%rip), %eax
        leal    3(%rax,%rax), %eax
        movl    %eax, result(%rip)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Should be careful that the compiler option should written in **upper case**.

Here is a [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/OqPFyD) website @JulianH gave which is really convenient to see assembler output among different platforms and different compilers.

I think get the assembler output helps me understand *as-if* rule better. I hope what I wrote would help someone who is also confusing about the abstract description of cppreference.